# How to redefine the HOME key press in Android, but only when my application is in the foreground

Tags: android

I want my app to handle the HOME key press with a custom action, and also stay in the foreground. I put the following code in AndroidManidest.xml:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        ....
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However, this has set my app as the new home screen, which I don't want. I only want to capture the key press while my app is in the foreground, just like you can capture other buttons. Is there any way to do that? Perhaps set the intent filter to only work while my app is in the foreground?

Comment: Why not try using [onUserLeaveHint()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onUserLeaveHint())

Comment: Is there a way to stop the user from actually leaving though?

Comment: It's not possible to prevent the user from killing an app.